Why can’t I install any Linux distros on my HP ProBook?
I am having installing 32-bit linux distros on my computer:

HP ProBook 6460b model XU550AV With Intel Celeron B810 clocked at 1.60 GHZ With HDD Toshiba M101ACF032 Drive Rev AAD AA0/AV001D SATA 320GB hard drive (I can sometimes format it to 298GB).

Every Linux distro failed to format my hard drive and stayed on the same percentage forever, or they gave an error message saying there was an error formatting my hard drive.
That is rather weird because Windows 7 and Windows 10 worked perfectly fine!
I tried:

Mageia 9
Q4OS
Linux Mint based on Debian (LMDE6)
MX Linux
Budhi

I also tried disabling HP DriveLock but it didn't work either.
It may be a long format but when installing Windows it sure didn't take hours!
Before any Linux distro attempt, Windows 7 said there was an error with my HDD but SMART HDD check never seen an error. I installed Windows 10 later and it did work but slow.
There could be an HDD error and I might buy a new HDD but I think it will be fine.

Yes, it's probably the drive. That it works when quick formatting is not an indication the drive is fine. Problems can and will occur when formatting during a Linux OS installation. Even for such an old machine replacing the old HDD with a new SSD is something to consider (480-512GB SSDs from alternative yet reliable brands can be found as low as $25). PS - Your system is 64-bit and surely you have more than 4GB RAM? Install any 64-BIT Linux with a light desktop environment, don't even bother with 32-bit, it's almost dead.

Changan i dont want to replace my pc...

But it made me happy knowing it is 64 bit!

But error said something about failed to communicate to SCSI or something and i retried a lot of times

And also i tried trisquel zorin and it didnt work

now starting ubuntu usb and it said X86 cpu outside txt disabled or something like that

I tried installing ubuntu and it displayed error translate it: Vytvorenie súborového systému na oblasti č.3 na SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb) zlyhalo. I think i need a new hard drive :(

You may have to replace the drive.

I paid 17,90€ for a 256 ssd... (Brand new) = Good investment

Changan Auto was right HDD was dead...

If your drive gets slow sometimes, then it could have a problem as it happened to me before.
Try testing its free space a few times with H2testw.
Of course it would be better to test the whole drive.
Also check if HD Tune gives reasonable results.

What does low free space has to do with it stalling when formatting the drive?

@ChanganAuto Nothing. H2testw is for testing the drive.

Frank Thanks for the recommednation...
